# Link list to multiple columns from another site

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I have an "Entity" List on site 1 showing all company details. Site 2 is for a specific project which i will need to select relevant parties involved in the project from the Entity list. So far i have created a customized form with powerapps with a drop down box showing all the company names.This works. The part i am stuck on and can't find info on is how to bring across the other details into the customized form, like the company phone number and contact name. Ideally when i select the company name from the drop down box on the form the rest of the fields populate then.

I am using Sharepoint on Office365

Thanks in advance.
Brett

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to show other column values based on the drop down column from another site.

Per my test, I follow this [article](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Auto-populate-Text-box-based-on-a-Dropdown-selected-value-in/td-p/504158) to auto populate Text box based on a Dropdown selected value in Sharepoint list column, I create a custom data card and insert the drop down input which display value from another site, when I try to set the **Update** property of the custom data card, there are no **Update** and **Default** properties for the custom data card.

Only those data cards generated from your data source would have the Update and Default property. If you want to bind the custom data card to a specific field in your SP list, you could consider enable the corresponding field data card within your Edit form, then made some changes to it.

So we suggest you customized the SharePoint list form, which contains drop down column directly, which means you need to keep the Entity list in the same site.

More information:

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Auto-populate-Text-box-based-on-a-Dropdown-selected-value-in/td-p/504158

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Custom-Card-Default-and-Update-Missing/td-p/552964

Comment: I followed the first link you provided and it successfully populates the text boxes with data from another list on another site based on the selection made in the drop down box. This works for adding a "New" record however when i hit the edit record i get the message "Getting your Data" and it never retrieves the record.  I have a couple of columns which i need to update with dates. I presume this is the issue you mention above. As a work around i can hit the info button and update the dates, that works.

Comment: Thank you for your update, if possible, could you share the detailed workaround and It will do great help to those who meet the similar question in this forum.